# pipenv: how to specify the minimum python version in the pipfile?

Tags: python, pipenv, pipfile

Is there a way in pipenv to specify the minimum version of python in the Pipfile?

Would something like this work?

```
[requires]
python_version = ">=python 3.5"
```

Comment: it seems they just support hard version pins for Python. There is an [issue on Github](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile/issues/87)

Comment: Thanks @lmiguelvargasf. I appreciate the prompt response. I hope that they will implement support for this feature down the road.

Comment: I agree with you. It would be awesome if they provide this feature.

Comment: To follow up on this, the devs have [explicitly](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1050#issuecomment-346203646) said that they will not be adding this feature - even though it puzzles quite a lot of users. [The issue.](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1050)

Comment: I agree @BramVanroy, I think this feature would be very handy. Hopefully the devs, given enough pressure from the community, change their mind on this and implement it. I would love to see pipenv ship with future versions of python and become the defacto standard for managing virtualenvs in the python language.

Answer (score 47):

No, `pipenv` does **not** support a minimum python version.  Per [pipenv issue 1050 feature request](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1050) on Sep 5, 2018, the `pipenv` authors have explicitly chosen not to implement it:

> This is not
> planned as a feature, not a bug, etc. it is a conscious choice to not
> pursue it, not simply ‘because it is hard’, but because we chose not
> to pursue it... we have thought about
> the implications of this decision. We have no plans to change it.

Note that you can specify:

```
 python_version = "3"
```

to allow any version of Python 3.  Not exactly what you asked for, but it might be sufficient for some projects.

Comment: for any version 3 of python, this is what worked for me python_version = "3"

Comment: I think this is the correct answer.  But I'd like to note that I've found that using "3" means that `pipenv check` will always fail.  This is because 3 != 3.8 or whatever version is used.  I presume that is in the backlog of things to fix.

Comment: This does not seem to with with version  2022.12.19 anymore. I get "Specifier python_version does not match 3 (3.8)." when running "pipenv check".

Comment: after reading that github issue i'm switching to poetry. the authors of pipenv are rude and dismissive

Answer (score 2):

As other answers explain, this is not supported in Pipenv and is never going to be supported by decision of the maintainers.

Instead, you can use [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/), which does not have such an attitude and does not have any problem with specifying an arbitrary version range for supported Python versions.