# Is there a way to specify minimum python version requirement for my script since pipfile does not support this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyenv

Is there a way to specify minimum python version requirement for my script ? For example my script requires python 3.6+ because it uses f-string. I have test my script under 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, they all work.

But since pipfile doesn't support minimum version, refer to [pipenv specify minimum version of python in pipfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51492423/pipenv-specify-minimum-version-of-python-in-pipfile) and this open issue https://github.com/pypa/pipfile/issues/87

So is there a way to do that ? Now I just write it in readme.

--- update ---

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2683 indeed said

> Note that the python_version key is optional. You can always remove it
> if it causes problems, and document the version requirements otherwise
> (i.e. in the README).

Answer (score 1):

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224736/how-to-write-python-code-that-is-able-to-properly-require-a-minimal-python-versi/6224814). This may do what you require:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] != 3 or sys.version_info[1] < 6:
    print("This script requires Python version 3.6")
    sys.exit(1)

# rest of script, including real initial imports, here
```

Comment: thanks, so that requires adding version check in my python script.

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment. Is this a question or a statement?

Comment: @Qiulang: Yes, that is what it means. However you do it will involve writing so code yourself.

Comment: @Albin sorry I meant a statement. I need to add the minimum version check in my script.